# Postgres date string from timestampz (ignore timezone)?

Tags: postgresql

My Query:

```
SELECT
  order_place_date,
  date(order_place_date AT TIME ZONE 'PST'),
  sum(item_quantity) units_shipped
  FROM "orders"
```

RESP

```
order_place_date            | date        | shipped
2019-06-29 20:24:09 -0700   | 2019-06-30  |  1
```

I would like the DATE to be returned as `2019-06-29` but cannot find any way to convert to a date or string without it being converted to `2019-06-30`.

I know I'm missing something.

Comment: BTW, what's your `timezone` setting (`SHOW timezone;`)?

Comment: I don;t think you have to deal with timezones in the database. It's the presentation layer that has to convert the timestamp to the format specified in the user's preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just found an answer using `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC-7'`

```
SELECT
  order_place_date,
  date(order_place_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC-7'),
  sum(item_quantity) units_shipped
  FROM "orders"
```